# switch color directly from highlighted color to another color

Tags: ios, swift

I have a `UIButton` on `mainStoryboard`. It has white `UIColor` and orange highlighted color.

I would like to change the color of this button right after the button is selected.

**ideal result**

```
White(default)　->　orange(highlighted)　->　green(animated)　->　white(default)
```

With the following code however, before the color changes from orange to green color it becomes white shortly.

**current result**

```
White(default)　->　orange(highlighted)　->　White(default)　-> green(animated)　->　white(default)
```

How can i switch color directly from highlighted orange color to green color?

```
    UIView.animate(withDuration:0, animations: { () -> Void in
        cell.buttons[index].backgroundColor = UIColor.green

    }) { (Bool) -> Void in
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: { () -> Void in
            cell.buttons[index].backgroundColor = UIColor.green

        }, completion: { (Bool) -> Void in
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0, animations: { () -> Void in
                cell.buttons[index].backgroundColor = UIColor.white
            }, completion:nil)
        })
    }
```

Comment: What is the type of your UIButton? Make sure it is set to Custom in the storyboard.

Comment: What method are you using to get an orange "highlighted color" for your button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your animation code looks okay but animation is a transaction between two states and it need time (duration). So try not to have an animation with duration 0 second because in that case, animation is useless.

Your problem seems to have mistakes made on button listeners. You want to change color to orange as soon as the button is clicked, that is `touchDown`. Then you want to do color change as soon as the button is released, which is `touchUpInside`

So try this out, add this code to your `viewDidLoad`

```
yourButton.addTarget(self, action:#selector(btnShowPasswordClickHoldDown), for: .touchDown)

yourButton.addTarget(self, action:#selector(btnShowPasswordClickRelease), for: .touchUpInside)
```

And then add the animation with a valid duration

```
func btnShowPasswordClickHoldDown(){
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: { () -> Void in
        self.yourButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange
    }, completion:nil)
}

func btnShowPasswordClickRelease(){
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: { () -> Void in
        self.yourButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.green

    }, completion: { (Bool) -> Void in
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: { () -> Void in
            self.yourButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        }, completion:nil)
    })
}
```